# how to checkbox for every _children in vue-ads-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```html
        <vue-ads-table
              :columns="fields"
              :rows="items"
              :selectable="true"                   
              @row-selected="onRowSelected"
              class="my-table"
        >
              <template slot="toggle-children-icon" slot-scope="props">
                <i class="mdi" :class="[props.expanded ? 'mdi-minus' : 'mdi-plus']"></i>
              </template> 

        </vue-ads-table>
```

I am using vue 2 with vuetify. i dont find any examples in vuetify official page.

i want to add checkbox for every _children rows in my items. below is my items array

```json
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "Name": "PanApps",
            "Code": "ORG",
            "Email": "Assyst@panApps.co",
            "Phone": "703-657-4700",
            "parentId": 0,
            "_children": [
                {
                    "_id": 172,
                    "Name": "test",
                    "Code": "tst1",
                    "Email": null,
                    "Phone": null,
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "_children": []
                },
                {
                    "_id": 173,
                    "Name": "testt",
                    "Code": "tst2",
                    "Email": null,
                    "Phone": null,
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "_children": []
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`v-checkbox`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/).

Probably would look like this in your table:

```html
<template slot="toggle-children-icon" slot-scope="props">
  <v-checkbox v-model="props.expanded"/>
</template>
```

(also try out `v-simple-checkbox`, it might look better in your table)